# Geometry artifacts on a mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, artifacts

I'm a newbie to 3D modelling, making a 3d mesh. I notices such strange artifacts on my model. Could you please help me to find the reason for it?
[image: screenshot with artifacts]

Applying rotation & scale makes it all even worse.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file, or at least the part you're talking about (copy paste the link it will give you): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: also, how did you created that hand? Also, did you use modifiers?

Comment: If I did it right here's the link with my blend project file: https://pasteall.org/blend/fd712d7f98be4c60810233f9f4abfd9b

I used subdivision surface and mirror modifiers as it's shown in the tutorial but mirror is already applied: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_X9v29i-Iw&list=RDCMUCyu4kn_ROhA34jug2g_AwJA&index=3

Comment: 1: It is the Solidify modifier that is causing the issue, why do you even need a solidify modifier? Turn the Thickness value right down to 0.01 or even better delete the solidify modifier. 2: 4 levels of subdivision is way to much, dial that back down to 1 and in edit mode with all of the character selected Face menu >Shade Smooth. The hands will still have hard edges because they have many edges Marked Sharp!? Again with  all selected, Edge menu > Clear Sharp.

Comment: Thank you very much! that was exactly the issue. You helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by solidify modifier. Deleting it gets rid of artifacts.